# Uncaught ReferenceError: model is not defined

Tags: javascript, three.js, reference, definition

I'm very new to JavaScript so for all I know you all could be cringing hard at what my code. Basically I'm trying to define a model imported via the Three.js GTLF Loader and define it as 'model' so I can make it automatically rotate.

My terminology is probably way off par but this is the only way I know how to explain what I'm doing and what needs fixing.

I'll just link my whole code but the error is evident here:

```
                        var model
                        var modelLoader = new GLTFLoader().setPath( 'models/DamagedHelmet/' );
                        modelLoader.load( 'DamagedHelmet.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

                            model = gltf.scene;
                            gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {

                                if ( child.isMesh ) {

                                    roughnessMipmapper.generateMipmaps( child.material );

                                }

                            } );

                            scene.add(model);

                            roughnessMipmapper.dispose();

                            render();

                        } );
```

I only defined the object as *model* so the object would automatically continuously rotate and I tried doing it here, a few lines of code below:

```
                function render() {

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

                model.rotation.x += 0.01;
                model.rotation.y += 0.005;

            }
```

There's probably something really obvious that I'm missing or doing wrong. All the solutions that I found online only seem to work if the Javascript isn't imported via module. (that's at least my guess)

Cheers guys.

Comment: There are two problems with your code. 1) your `model` variable is not visible by the `render` function, define it in the outside scope of where the function is declared. 2) `GLTFLoader` loads the model asynchronously, until the model is completely loaded `model` is undefined. Which means your `model.rotation.x` will also return an error, check if `model` is not undefined before rotating.

Comment: @ScieCode Is it alright if you explain as to how I'd go about that? Sorry I'm really new to JavaScript

Comment: An easy way is to declare `var model;` at the global scope, it will, then be available to all functions. For the rotation part, just check `if ( model !== undefined )` and then proceed with the rotation.

Comment: https://eloquentjavascript.net/ Highly recommend this book on Javascript. It goes over very important javascript concepts as variable/function scope, hoisting and closures.

Answer (score 0):

Gltf is kind of a pain but for your problem depending if you're using node or à local script be sure to add(for node) :

```
import { GLTFLoader } from '../../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
```

in order to add GLTFLoader to your project

Once you've done that you could try to make sure not to cross the CORS policy which is making sure that you allow same-origin in your header, if you use express this gives you something like :

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) =>{
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
next()
  });
```

[source](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled)

And then you have to make sur that all those files :

```
"buffers" : [
    {
        "byteLength" : 558504,
        "uri" : "DamagedHelmet.bin"
    }
],
"images" : [
    {
        "uri" : "Default_albedo.jpg"
    },
    {
        "uri" : "Default_metalRoughness.jpg"
    },
    {
        "uri" : "Default_emissive.jpg"
    },
    {
        "uri" : "Default_AO.jpg"
    },
    {
        "uri" : "Default_normal.jpg"
    }
],
```

listed in DamagedHelmet are also available and don't break CORS policy only then you might use your code which seems correct to me